# Looking up Data from a table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I need help please.  I'm sure it is simple to do, I just can't get it right!  I need to pull data from a table based on a field in my current table and a field in a different table.

I have a table that stores different codes like this:

```
  category   grp     code     description

ACT TAKEN     1       10      Control

ACT TAKEN     2       20      Locate

ALM METHOD    2       20      Phone
```

Image:

[image: Screenshot of table]

The code is what is stored in my data.  I need to pull the description based off of the code and the category.  For instance, for the Actions taken code of 10, I would look at the table in the category and find 'ACT TAKEN' and the pull the description for the code 10 with that category.

I will also need to pull the grp field in some cases based off of the code and category.

Help!!

Comment: what are you using as a data source? SQL Server or something like that?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the table structures for all relevant tables, plus any relationships between them. Also post what you have tried so far, it will make it easier to understand what output you are trying to achieve.